# One or more arguments are invalid error when calling a Com+ application

Tags: vb6, com+

I have vb6 / com+ application which was working fine for weeks until earlier today.  According to everyone with access nothing was done to the server.  When I try to call the com+ component on the server, I get the following error:

Error Code -2147024809 One or more arguments are invalid.

If I switch to hit a different com+ server everything works fine.

I've tried restarting the com+ package, restarting IIS, and recreating the package, but none of this has worked.

Has anyone run into this before?

Comment: Did you ever confirm what caused this?

Comment: No.  And it hasn't come back either.  I'm sure it's only a matter of time before it returns again...

Comment: I have the same problem when the application receives a lot of incoming requests. I'm using appartment thread-model and delphi.

Answer (score 1):

I bet you have installed this and your Server has gone fubar.
Had this issue too. Grrr MS Sec Updates Grrr.

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/fd24c76b-a8d7-4033-8e31-6dbe236d92f7.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: It randomly started working a couple of hours after it randomly stopped working.  I'll talk to my admin to see if this update was installed.  I am always uncomfortable after a problem has "magically" fixed itself.

Thanks